# Mongodb query to find document matching a particular range

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query, nosql

I have a problem in which I am getting distance between two geolocations. I have a MongoDB collection in which I have documents that have min_distance, max_distance, and price. I need a query to fetch the price for the distance that I have calculated.
[image: Below is my mongodb collection]

Comment: Please don't paste screenshots, use formatted text. See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this one:

```
distance = 15    
db.collection.find({
   min_distance: { $lt: distance },
   max_distance: { $gt: distance }
})
```

Or you can use expression:

```
db.collection.find({
   $expr: {
      $and: [
         { $gt: ["$min_distance", distance] },
         { $lt: ["$max_distance", distance] }
      ]
   }
})
```

[Mongo Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/76PN8fSOfG5)

Comment: Hey, thanks for replying but I have tried both these queries and its returning nothing!

Comment: Please provide sample documents as text, then I will test.

Comment: [{
  "_id": {
    "$oid": "64206a8d6368ab8e37a6a084"
  },
  "price": "10",
  "min_distance": 0,
  "max_distance": 5
},{
  "_id": {
    "$oid": "64206a8d6368ab8e37a6a085"
  },
  "price": "15",
  "max_distance": 11,
  "min_distance": 6
}]

Comment: Mixed the operator, now it should work